# ng2-datetime: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I've installed the jQuery typings and all the project dependencies. But I really can't wrap my head around this one.

template source (jade):

```
.form-group
      .col-sm-4
        label Birth Date
        datetime(name="birthDate", [(ngModel)]="transaction.general_information.birthDate")
...
```

module source (ts):

```
import { NKDatetimeModule } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    NKDatetimeModule
  ],...
})
...
```

**Error (Dev Console Chrome):**

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./OrdersNewStep1 class OrdersNewStep1 - inline template:0:1046 caused by: jQuery is not defined
```

Github project:
[ng2-datetime](https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime)

Using:

- Angular2
- Webpack

Comment: What loader do you use? For some jQuery plugins using webpack you have to define them with Provide plugin http://pastebin.com/HnrAYeWX

Comment: Thanks! I got a new error!.. If I got a dollar for every headache webpack has given me, I would hire someone to handle this shit for me :P

Comment: @icewind Could you please answer, your comment was correct. The issue was the webpack loader.

Comment: Sure. Added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebPack is placing all modules into an isolated scopes. Meanwhile, most of plugins expect jQuery to be defined in a global scope. You can fix it using [Provide plugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) for webpack like this

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})
```